# In biblatex, how to change pp. to p. when referring to pages of references?

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

I want to use `\cites` command to cite references with different pages. I get the following output

[image]

As you see, `biblatex` refers to page numbers by `pp.`. How to set it to `p.`?

My MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{kerr2018introduction,
        title={Introduction to Energy and Climate - Developing a Sustainable Environment},
        author={Julie Kerr},
        edition={1},
        year={2018},
        publisher={CRC Press}
    }
    @book{kanoğlu2010fundamentals,
        title={Fundamentals and Applications of Renewable Energy},
        author={Kanoğlu, Mehmet and Çengel, Yunus and Cimbala, John},
        edition={1},
        year={2020},
        publisher={McGraw Hill}
    }
    @book{twidell2015renewable,
        title={Renewable Energy Resources},
        author={Twidell, John and Weir, Tony},
        edition={3},
        year={2015},
        publisher={Routledge}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic, sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewcommand*{\multipostnotedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

\begin{document}
    
    \cites(see)(11, 11, 1961){kerr2018introduction}{kanoğlu2010fundamentals}{twidell2015renewable}
    
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are citing several pages `pp.` appears to be correct, you can -- non the less -- force `p.` with the command `\pno`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{kerr2018introduction,
        title={Introduction to Energy and Climate - Developing a Sustainable Environment},
        author={Julie Kerr},
        edition={1},
        year={2018},
        publisher={CRC Press}
    }
    @book{kanoğlu2010fundamentals,
        title={Fundamentals and Applications of Renewable Energy},
        author={Kanoğlu, Mehmet and Çengel, Yunus and Cimbala, John},
        edition={1},
        year={2020},
        publisher={McGraw Hill}
    }
    @book{twidell2015renewable,
        title={Renewable Energy Resources},
        author={Twidell, John and Weir, Tony},
        edition={3},
        year={2015},
        publisher={Routledge}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic, sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewcommand*{\multipostnotedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

\begin{document}
    
    \cites(see)(\pno~11, 11, 1961){kerr2018introduction}{kanoğlu2010fundamentals}{twidell2015renewable}
    
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I got it, you just need to add

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    page={p\adddot},%
    pages={p\adddot},%
}
```

MWE

```
    \begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{kerr2018introduction,
        title={Introduction to Energy and Climate - Developing a Sustainable Environment},
        author={Julie Kerr},
        edition={1},
        year={2018},
        publisher={CRC Press}
    }
    @book{kanoğlu2010fundamentals,
        title={Fundamentals and Applications of Renewable Energy},
        author={Kanoğlu, Mehmet and Çengel, Yunus and Cimbala, John},
        edition={1},
        year={2020},
        publisher={McGraw Hill}
    }
    @book{twidell2015renewable,
        title={Renewable Energy Resources},
        author={Twidell, John and Weir, Tony},
        edition={3},
        year={2015},
        publisher={Routledge}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic, sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewcommand{\multipostnotedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    page={p\adddot},%
    pages={p\adddot},%
}

\begin{document}
    
    \cites(see)(11, 11, 1961){kerr2018introduction}{kanoğlu2010fundamentals}{twidell2015renewable}
    
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
    
\end{document}
```